# using sed's back references as function arguments

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm struggling to pass back references from `sed` as an argument to a function.

Here's an example

```
join() { sep="$1"; shift; echo -n "$1"; shift; printf "$sep%s" "$@"; }
index_of() {
  local value="${1}"
  shift
  local array=("${@}")
  for (( i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++ )); do
    if [ "${array[$i]}" = $value ]; then
      echo $i
    fi
  done
}

array=('foo' 'bar' 'baz')
regex=$(join '\|' "${array[@]}")
echo 'baz' 'bar' 'foo' | sed "s/\(${regex}\)/[$(index_of "\1" ${array[@]})] \1/g"
```

I'm expecting this to output `baz [2] bar [1] foo [0]`, but it's returning `baz [] bar [] foo []` since this passes `'\1'` as value, instead of the match from `sed`.

How can I pass the actual match as an argument instead?

Comment: Due to the [order of expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions), the command substitution is  being executed **before** sed is launched.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, you need to rethink how you're going about it.

Here's a rewrite:

```
index_of() {
    local value=$1 arrayname=$2    # we're passing the array by name
    local tmp="${arrayname}[@]"    # and then jumping through a hoop
    local array=("${!tmp}")        # to get the values

    # this is just a different way of iterating through the array
    local i=0
    for elem in "${array[@]}"; do
        if [[ $elem == $value ]]; then
            echo $i
            break       # save some time when a match is found
        fi
        ((i++))
    done
}

array=('foo' 'bar' 'baz')

# here's the big change: have to call the function in the same context
# as iterating through the words.
# in other words, call the shell function from the same shell
for word in baz bar foo; do
    printf "%s [%d] " "$word" $(index_of "$word" "array")
done
```

Also, a more efficient `join` function

```
join() { 
    local IFS="$1"
    shift
    echo "$*"
}
```

Comment: thanks, I guess I'll have to change my approach here